# Import data from XML to SQL Server tables

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, xml, import

I have problem with importing data from xml into SQL Server tables.

This example of my XML file:

```
<ORDER>
  <ORDER_HEADER>
    <NUMBER>109</NUMBER>
  </ORDER_HEADER>
  <CUSTOMER_HEADER>
    <CUSTOMER>Michael</CUSTOMER>    
  </CUSTOMER_HEADER>
  <ORDER_ITEMS>
    <ITEM>
      <CATALOG_NUMBER>2</CATALOG_NUMBER>
      <VAT>21</VAT>
    </ITEM>
    <ITEM>
      <CATALOG_NUMBER>5</CATALOG_NUMBER>
      <VAT>21</VAT>
    </ITEM>
    <ITEM>
      <CATALOG_NUMBER>7</CATALOG_NUMBER>
      <VAT>21</VAT>
    </ITEM>
    <ITEM>
      <CATALOG_NUMBER>9</CATALOG_NUMBER>
      <VAT>21</VAT>
    </ITEM>
  </ORDER_ITEMS>
</ORDER>
```

And this is my c# code:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("C:\\Users\\L\\order.xml");
var NUMBER = doc.Descendants("NUMBER");                
var CUSTOMER = doc.Descendants("CUSTOMER");
var CATALOG_NUMBER = doc.Descendants("CATALOG_NUMBER");
var VAT = doc.Descendants("VAT");

SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("*****");
   conn.Open();
      foreach (var cislo in NUMBER)
        {
          using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
               cmd.CommandText="Insert INTO ORDER_HEADER(NUMBER) VALUES (@cislo);";
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cislo",cislo.Value);
               cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
               cmd.Clone();
             }
        }
      foreach (var zakaznik in CUSTOMER)
        {
           using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
             {
               cmd.CommandText="Insert INTO CUSTOMER_HEAD(CUSTOMER)VALUES(@zakaznik);";
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@zakaznik", zakaznik.Value);
               cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
               cmd.Clone();
              }
        }
      foreach (var katalo_cislo in CATALOG_NUMBER)
        foreach (var vat1 in VAT)
           {
              using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
                 {
                    cmd.CommandText = "Insert INTO ITEM (CATALOG_NUMBER,VAT) VALUES (@katalo_cislo,@vat1);";
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@katalo_cislo", katalo_cislo.Value);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vat1", vat1.Value);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    cmd.Clone();
                  }
           }
    conn.Close();
```

But first 2 sql tables is OK, but in last sql table ITEM is more than 4 record...problem is probably in  two FOREACH... but how could I load records from `ORDER_ITEMS` right?

Thanks

This is my code now with all my values:
¨

```
var Items = doc.Descendants("ITEM").Select(x => new { NUMBER = (int?)x.Element("NUMBER"), CATALOG_NUMBER = (string)x.Element("CATALOG_NUMBER"), ITEM_NAME = (string)x.Element("ITEM_NAME"), UNIT = (string)x.Element("UNIT"), AMOUNT = (int?)x.Element("AMOUNT"), PRICE_WITHOUT_VAT = (string)x.Element("PRICE_WITHOUT_VAT"), VAT = (string)x.Element("VAT"), PRICE_VAT = (string)x.Element("PRICE_VAT"), EAN = (string)x.Element("EAN"), SUPPLIER_ITEM_NUMBER = (string)x.Element("SUPPLIER_ITEM_NUMBER"), SUPPLIER_ID = (string)x.Element("SUPPLIER_ID"), SUPPLIER_NAME = (string)x.Element("SUPPLIER_NAME"), ORDER_ITEMS_Id = (string)x.Element("ORDER_ITEMS_Id"), }).ToList();
                foreach (var item in Items)
                                            {
                                                using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
                                                {
                                                    cmd.CommandText = "Insert INTO ITEM (NUMBER,CATALOG_NUMBER,ITEM_NAME,UNIT,AMOUNT,PRICE_WITHOUT_VAT,VAT,PRICE_VAT,EAN,SUPPLIER_ITEM_NUMBER,SUPPLIER_ID,SUPPLIER_NAME,ORDER_ITEMS_Id) VALUES (@cislo,@katalo_cislo,@nazev_zbozi,@jednotka,@mnozstvi,@cenabezvat,@vat1,@cenavat,@ean1,@dodav_cislo,@dodav_id,@dodav_jmeno,@objednavkaid);";
                                                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cislo", item.NUMBER);
                                                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@katalo_cislo", item.CATALOG_NUMBER);
                                                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nazev_zbozi", item.ITEM_NAME);
                                                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@jednotka", item.UNIT);
                                                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mnozstvi", item.AMOUNT);
                                                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cenabezvat", item.PRICE_WITHOUT_VAT);
                                                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vat1", item.VAT);
                                                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cenavat", item.PRICE_VAT);
                                                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ean1", item.EAN);
                                                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dodav_cislo", item.SUPPLIER_ITEM_NUMBER);
                                                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dodav_id", item.SUPPLIER_ID);
                                                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dodav_jmeno", item.SUPPLIER_NAME);
                                                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@objednavkaid", item.ORDER_ITEMS_Id);
                                                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                                    //cmd.Clone();
                                                }
                                            }
```

Comment: You can create a dataset from your xml `DataSet ds = new DataSet(); ds.ReadXml(XDocument.Load(fname).CreateReader());` and then insert it directly to DB using SqlDataAdapter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach (var katalo_cislo in CATALOG_NUMBER)
foreach (var vat1 in VAT){}
```

above code will insert `(no of CATALOG_NUMBER)* (no of VAT)` records to the database, i think you need to insert Items to Item Table. Then you can simply select the `ITEM` nodes and insert them in to table as below

```
var Items = doc.Descendants("ITEM")
        .Select(x=> new {CATALOG_NUMBER= (string)x.Element("CATALOG_NUMBER"), 
                        VAT = (int?)x.Element("VAT")} ).ToList();
foreach( var item in Items)
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "Insert INTO ITEM (CATALOG_NUMBER,VAT) VALUES (@katalo_cislo,@vat1);";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@katalo_cislo", item.CATALOG_NUMBER);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vat1", (object)item.VAT??DBNull.Value);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: Now i have this error: The value of element can not be NULL...:/

Comment: @Kate in your xml for one item there is no VAT value. So above code will insert null value for that, what exactly you want to do if vat is null?

Comment: sorry, please explain your requirement

Comment: i want only take values od CATALOG_NUMBEr and VAT and give to sql table...but when i have more foreach i have a let of records...And i want when i have 4 ITEMS in XML file 4 record in SQL table...sorry for my bad English..

Comment: @Kate are you still get same error? if you get errors you many need to allow null in your VAT column in database table

Comment: In First post i have only sample of my code..i have more values..I will update my first post and give you solution in my case...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36838/discussion-between-damith-and-kate)